# Need pyodbc dll for Python 2.6 under Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, python-2.6, pyodbc

I wanted to know what version of **pyodbc dll** could be used for 
**Python 2.6** under **Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise** and appreciate if link for the same will be provided.

Although i got all versions of pyodbc.exe [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/) but i would be needing dlls compatible with above mentioned operating system. Best

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty straightforward...use either the [32-bit](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/detail?name=pyodbc-3.0.6.win32-py2.6.exe&can=2&q=) or [64-bit](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/downloads/detail?name=pyodbc-3.0.6.win-amd64-py2.6.exe&can=2&q=) installer based on your server's processor architecture.